# Is there a way to search a txt file for a list of values?

Tags: windows, windows-10, csv, text-editors

I have a big txt file and a list of comma separated values. Is there a way to search the text file and show me which values were not found inside the text file?

Comment: See `for /?` to read your csv. Use `Findstr /?` which sets an `errorlevel` if found or not.

Comment: Yes, it's easy & possible. On Windows 10, you should be using PowerShell. Edit you question to show example .csv & example text file.